# GARCH model analysis using python

Tags: python, finance, forecasting, quantitative-finance, volatility

I have a AR(3)-GJR-GARCH(2,2,2) model. How can I test the presence of ‘leverage effects’ ((i.e. asymmetric responses of the condi- tional variance to the positive and negative shocks)) with 5% significance level?

Below is my code for model:

```
startdate = '2009-01-01'
enddate = '2021-12-31'
data = yf.download('GD', start = startdate, end = enddate)
data.rename(columns={"Adj Close": "price"}, inplace = True)
log_returns = np.log(data['price']/data['price'].shift(1))*100 # Log return in %
log_returns.dropna(inplace = True)
startdate = '2010-01-01'
enddate = '2018-12-31'
in_sample_return = log_returns.loc[startdate:enddate]
gjr_garch = arch_model(in_sample_return,mean='AR',lags=3,vol='GARCH',p=2,o=2,q=2,dist='t').fit(update_freq=5)
```

What do I do next to check if ‘leverage effects’ is present at 5% significance level?

As I know the gamma parameter is the leverage and when gamma is non-zero it means that the model has leverage effect, but the problem is here in this model I have two gamma parameters.

I thought checking gamma coefficient is enough but as it mentioned "5% significance level" , I believe the p_value needs to be calculated and I'm not sure how do I do it.